# MySQL- How to select distinct data against a same record

Tags: mysql, distinct-values, sqlfiddle

Referring to the question asked. I have a table which includes multiple records for the same entry like below image

[image]

All I want is to select the single record against each entry. I have also set the DB and Query in [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2BftScoRwB739YiiMoL9jY/0)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: i can see there is little bit time fraction , do you need a single entry for each date?

Comment: You've posted an empty link

Comment: @Strawberry Kindly see it now

Comment: Reason for down vote ?

Comment: You'll have to add a additional column for referring to single row with much less complexity in query and to be reliable say like a ID column

Comment: @NareshKumar I can't perform any operation(s) other than `select` on the table.

Comment: Ok then use nested query to select rows and then again select distinct row from the obtained selection

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From discussion got you need convert datetime to date and `group by` clause column to date

for your table

```
SELECT  p.`zdjh` AS MSN, max(p.`sjsj`) AS Date_Time,max( p.`xhqd`) AS Ping 
FROM `tj_xhqd` p
WHERE p.`sjsj` <='2018-07-24 10:15:00' AND p.`sjsj` >='2018-07-23 10:15:00'
group by zdjh
ORDER BY MSN, Date_Time, Ping DESC
```

Comment: All times are distinct

Comment: down voter can you please say the reason of downvote?

Comment: @Strawberry and thats why i asked him what  he needs?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Kindly see my fork [query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2BftScoRwB739YiiMoL9jY/0)

Comment: @MrFaisal i changed my query according to your table structure

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin did you tried to run it in the [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2BftScoRwB739YiiMoL9jY/0)? Because I can see it makes no difference as I am still not able to see single record

Comment: @MrFaisal https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2BftScoRwB739YiiMoL9jY/0 check this

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I have seen it. But still it's no giving me single record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176610/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-mr-faisal).